# Split a time range into pieces by other time ranges

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, time

I have a complicated task that I have been beating my head against the wall now for a few days. I've tried about 4 different approaches, however each seems to stall and it is becoming extremely frustrating.

I have a time range. For example, 14:30:00 until 18:30:00. Consider this time range somebody's work shift. During this time range, they state they cannot work from 15:30:00 until 16:30:00 and from 17:30:00 until 18:30:00. I need to modify the original shift's start and end times to remove the conflicting shifts.

The original shift array looks like this:

```
$original_shift[0]['start'] = '14:30:00';
$original_shift[0]['end']   = '18:30:00';
```

And the time ranges to be removed from the original shift look like this:

```
$subshift[0]['start'] = '15:30:00';
$subshift[0]['end']   = '16:30:00';
$subshift[1]['start'] = '17:30:00';
$subshift[1]['end']   = '18:30:00';
```

Here is a visualization:

[image]

So, I basically need my original shift to look like this when I'm done:

```
$original_shift[0]['start'] = '14:30:00';
$original_shift[0]['end']   = '15:30:00';
$original_shift[1]['start'] = '16:30:00';
$original_shift[1]['end']   = '17:30:00';
```

Some complications that I also need to consider are:

1. These time ranges may be any times (not constrained to the half hour as I have used in my example), however I will know with 100% certainty the the unavailable time ranges will always start and end on or in between the original shift's start and end times.
2. Unavailable times may butt up and/or take the entire original shift's time up.

I'm not looking for someone to "write my code" as much as I am looking for someone who has dealt with something like this in the past and may have some insight on how they accomplished it.

Comment: I've made some clarifications, however the last code block doesn't show how to do it, it shows what I need the end product to produce.

Comment: can the original shift already be segmented, e.g. can it already contain unavailable time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you specifically asked for "some insight" rather than a full working answer, I'd personally go with arrays populated with "minutes".

```
$shift = array(
    'start' => '15:30:00',
    'end' => '18:30:00',

    'original' => array(),
    'unavailable' => array(),
    'modified' => array()
);
```

You'd then do some jiggery pokery to convert `15:30:00` into 930 and `18:30:00` into 1110 (number of minutes) which will give you the difference between start and end times.

Use `range()` to quickly fill up the `original` array, load in your `unavailable` in a similar format and then use things like `array_intersect()` and `array_diff()` to work out which minutes from the original shift are unavailable.

From that, build up the `modified` array, and read directly from there to your output.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, it never occurred to me to work with the time in minutes (as an integer). I actually have the times in minute-based integers from a previous step, so this meshed well with what I was originally doing. I was able to come up with a solution with a little more work beyond what you had suggested, but you helped put me on the right thought path.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do calculations of time-ranges. As the image shows this seems like a simple subtraction. It would be nice to just have objects that do these.

I had no code for this ready, so the following concept is a bit rough although probably not that bad.

A `Range` type that represents a time from-to. Those are as `DateTime` so that the benefits of these existing types can be used. I didn't use much of the benefits so far, however for the rest of the application this can make sense.

The `Range` type already contains some basic comparison methods I thought were useful to do parts of the calculations.

However as an object can not divide itself into two I also created a `Ranges` type which can represent one or more `Range`s. This was necessary to have something that can be "divided".

I cheated a little here because I implemented the difference calculation as a member of `Range`, returning an array with one or multiple `Range` objects. The final calculation then is just having a shift and substract the unavailable ranges from it:

```
$shift = new Ranges(new DateTime('14:30:00'), new DateTime('18:30:00'));

$unavailables = new Ranges([
    new Range(new DateTime('15:30:00'), new DateTime('16:30:00')),
    new Range(new DateTime('17:30:00'), new DateTime('18:30:00')),
]);

$shift->subtract($unavailables);
```

The shift then spans:

```
14:30:00 - 15:30:00
16:30:00 - 17:30:00
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/43205); [Gist](https://gist.github.com/hakre/6859a19fa9108ba0173d)

I can not say if it is worth the abstraction, what is nice with `DateTime` objects is that you can compare them with `>`, `<` and `=`. The real benefit from these classes might shed into light when you need more calculations between Range and Ranges. Maybe the interface is not sweet yet, however the basic calculations behind are outlined in the code already.

One caveat: The difference between `14:00-15:00` and `14:00-15:00` in my code will result to `14:00-14:00`. I keep the start time to not run empty, but you can run empty, too. The Ranges object should handle it nicely.

Comment: There were some flaws for the inverse operations, I updated the gist, and an updated demo is here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/jy2Uz5

Comment: Thank you, this code looks very promising. I probably would have accepted it as the answer (I prefer DateTime when possible), however a precursor (and something I omitted) is that the step before this, I was converting time from it in straight up minutes (e.g. 480 for 8am) to a DateTime object. Joe's solution below suggested working directly with a minute-only version of the time, which somehow never occurred to me. His solution works and saves me a step, which is the only reason I'm choosing to select his as the answer. Thank you very much though for the work you put into this answer!

Comment: Internally this thingy is an array, too, however I spare to keep ranges of numbers (one element per minute) by doing start/end comparisons. It would equally work with minute start and end values and I even thought about making these ranges more abstract because I once (not time based) had some similar need. Was fun to write it, it's also done pretty quick, I'm not fully satisfied with the names of the methods. But even if you work with arrays I suggest to form a base type out of it to put the range and methods together to keep the code lean. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

The code should speak for itself:

```
$original_shift[0]['start'] = '14:30:00';
$original_shift[0]['end'] = '18:30:00';

$breaks[0]['start'] = '14:30:00';
$breaks[0]['end'] = '15:30:00';
$breaks[1]['start'] = '16:30:00';
$breaks[1]['end'] = '17:30:00';

$modified_shift = array(
    array('start' => $original_shift[0]['start'])
);

for($x = 0, $y = count($breaks), $z = 0; $x < $y; $x++){
    $modified_shift[$z]['end'] = $breaks[$x]['start'];
    if($modified_shift[$z]['end'] != $modified_shift[$z]['start']){
        $z++;       
    }
    $modified_shift[$z]['start'] = $breaks[$x]['end'];
}

$modified_shift[$z]['end'] = $original_shift[0]['end'];

if($modified_shift[$z]['end'] == $modified_shift[$z]['start']){
    unset($modified_shift[$z]);
}
```