# Split a date array into available shifts to work?

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

OK I have the following:

```
    ["dates"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1322 (4) {
    ["availday"]=>
    string(10) "2015-04-23"
    ["availhoursstart"]=>
    string(5) "12:00"
    ["availhoursend"]=>
    string(5) "22:00"
    ["unavail"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1326 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "16:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "17:00"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#1325 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "19:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "20:00"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#1324 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "20:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "21:00"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#1327 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "13:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "14:00"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#1321 (4) {
    ["availday"]=>
    string(10) "2015-04-24"
    ["availhoursstart"]=>
    string(5) "12:00"
    ["availhoursend"]=>
    string(5) "22:00"
    ["unavail"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1323 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "16:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "17:00"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#1328 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "21:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "22:00"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#1331 (2) {
        ["start"]=>
        string(5) "20:00"
        ["end"]=>
        string(5) "21:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where the `["availhoursstart"]=> string(5) "12:00" ["availhoursend"]=> string(5) "22:00"` is the available work shit and the unavail array contains the hours the worker has allready been booked. 
You do i go about splitting the avail hours into sections removing the items that have allready been booked? 
I've tried using @hakre's example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129336/split-a-time-range-into-pieces-by-other-time-ranges) but I'm failing...

I've tried this:

```
                        foreach($date_sub as $keydates => $valuedates){

                        foreach($valuedates->dates as $key => $value){

                                $shift = new Ranges(new DateTime($value->availhoursstart), new DateTime($value->availhoursend));

                                $i = 0;
                                foreach($value->unavail as $keysubsub => $valuesubsub){

                                    $unavails[$i] = new Range(new DateTime($valuesubsub->start), new DateTime($valuesubsub->end));

                                        $i++;

                                }


                                $unavailables = new Ranges($unavails[$i]);




                                $shift->substract($unavailables);
                                $x = 0;
                                foreach ($shift as $range) {

                                        $valuedates->dates[$key]->avail[$x] = $range->format('H:i:s');


                                        $x++;

                                }
                        }

                    }

                    echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump( $date_sub );
                    echo "</pre>";
```

but it returns wrong:

```
    ["dates"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1322 (5) {
        ["availday"]=>
        string(10) "2015-04-23"
        ["availhoursstart"]=>
        string(5) "12:00"
        ["availhoursend"]=>
        string(5) "22:00"
        ["unavail"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#1326 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "16:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "17:00"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#1325 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "19:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "20:00"
          }
          [2]=>
          object(stdClass)#1324 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "20:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "21:00"
          }
          [3]=>
          object(stdClass)#1327 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "13:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "14:00"
          }
        }
        ["avail"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "12:00:00"
            [1]=>
            string(8) "22:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#1321 (5) {
        ["availday"]=>
        string(10) "2015-04-24"
        ["availhoursstart"]=>
        string(5) "12:00"
        ["availhoursend"]=>
        string(5) "22:00"
        ["unavail"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#1323 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "16:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "17:00"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#1328 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "21:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "22:00"
          }
          [2]=>
          object(stdClass)#1331 (2) {
            ["start"]=>
            string(5) "20:00"
            ["end"]=>
            string(5) "21:00"
          }
        }
        ["avail"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "12:00:00"
            [1]=>
            string(8) "13:00:00"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "14:00:00"
            [1]=>
            string(8) "22:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My expected output is very similar to this last snippet where the unavail array contains the unavailable times in an array and a array of the available dates. Like i said I've tried a few permutations of Hakre's code but to no avail...

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: the main problem I'm running into is that the times overlap or at least but up to oneanother, I've gone through about 10 permutaions of @hakre's gist it's some elegant code!

Comment: just updated with a little bit more info

Comment: @vimes1984 What would be the expected output?

Comment: Post your expected output too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a little corrected your code :)

```
foreach($date_sub as $keydates => $valuedates){
    foreach($valuedates->dates as $key => $value){
        $shift = new Ranges(new DateTime($value->availhoursstart), new DateTime($value->availhoursend));

        foreach($value->unavail as $ukey =>$valuesubsub){
// substract unavaiiable time range
            $shift->substract(new Ranges(new DateTime($valuesubsub->start), new DateTime($valuesubsub->end)));
// and remove that range from array
            unset($value->unavail[$ukey]);
        }

        foreach ($shift as $range)
// Add to array as avail
            $valuedates->dates[$key]->avail[] = $range->format('H:i:s');

// Making new unavaliables. Set all open time
        $unavails = new Ranges(new DateTime($value->availhoursstart), new DateTime($value->availhoursend));
// Substract shift ranges
        $unavails->substract($shift);
// Output to array as unavail
        foreach ($unavails as $range)
            $valuedates->dates[$key]->unavail[] = $range->format('H:i:s');
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
// Watching result
var_dump( $date_sub );
echo "</pre>";
```