# How to disjunct two arrays of datetime ranges in php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I disjunct two arrays of time ranges in PHP?

I have two arrays:

1. Availability (it's ranges when user is available) and
2. Dates (it's ranges when user have a date)

Availability

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 00:00:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 15:00:00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 17:00:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 19:30:00
    )
```

Dates

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 08:00:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 12:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 18:30:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 19:30:00
    )
```

And I have disjunct all dates from availability. If you can't understand what I'm talking about, this is what I should have on exit of this disjunction:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 00:00:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 8:00:00
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 12:00:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 15:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 17:00:00
        [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-21 18:30:00
    )
```

It could be even ranges not just in one day like 
`[dateTimeStart] => 2016-07-21 17:00:00
            [dateTimeEnd] => 2016-07-22 01:30:00`

. Please, help me with it or show where I have to go.

Comment: look at class Range - https://gist.github.com/hakre/6859a19fa9108ba0173d - it's work for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a time range into pieces by other time ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129336/split-a-time-range-into-pieces-by-other-time-ranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [splash58 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511064/how-to-disjunct-two-arrays-of-datetime-ranges-in-php#comment64420109_38511064), here's a demonstration of [hakre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131798/4233593) for this question:

```
$shift = new Ranges([
    new Range(new DateTime('2016-07-21 00:00:00'), new DateTime('2016-07-21 15:00:00')),
    new Range(new DateTime('2016-07-21 17:00:00'), new DateTime('2016-07-21 19:30:00')),
]);

$unavailables = new Ranges([
    new Range(new DateTime('2016-07-21 08:00:00'), new DateTime('2016-07-21 12:00:00')),
    new Range(new DateTime('2016-07-21 18:30:00'), new DateTime('2016-07-21 19:30:00')),
]);

print_r($shift);
```

> ```
> Ranges Object
> (
>     [ranges:protected] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => Range Object
>                 (
>                     [start:protected] => DateTime Object
>                         (
>                             [date] => 2016-07-21 00:00:00
>                             [timezone_type] => 3
>                             [timezone] => America/Chicago
>                         )
>
>                     [end:protected] => DateTime Object
>                         (
>                             [date] => 2016-07-21 08:00:00
>                             [timezone_type] => 3
>                             [timezone] => America/Chicago
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>             [1] => Range Object
>                 (
>                     [start:protected] => DateTime Object
>                         (
>                             [date] => 2016-07-21 12:00:00
>                             [timezone_type] => 3
>                             [timezone] => America/Chicago
>                         )
>
>                     [end:protected] => DateTime Object
>                         (
>                             [date] => 2016-07-21 15:00:00
>                             [timezone_type] => 3
>                             [timezone] => America/Chicago
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>             [2] => Range Object
>                 (
>                     [start:protected] => DateTime Object
>                         (
>                             [date] => 2016-07-21 17:00:00
>                             [timezone_type] => 3
>                             [timezone] => America/Chicago
>                         )
>
>                     [end:protected] => DateTime Object
>                         (
>                             [date] => 2016-07-21 18:30:00
>                             [timezone_type] => 3
>                             [timezone] => America/Chicago
>                         )
>
>                 )
>
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Here's [the source code](https://gist.github.com/hakre/6859a19fa9108ba0173d) for reference in case [the link](https://gist.github.com/hakre/6859a19fa9108ba0173d) is broken.

```
/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129336/split-a-time-range-into-pieces-by-other-time-ranges
 * @link https://gist.github.com/gists/3977645
 * @author hakre
 */
class Range
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $start;
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $end;
    public function __construct(DateTime $start, DateTime $end) {
        $this->setStart($start);
        $this->setEnd($end);
    }
    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getStart() {
        return $this->start;
    }
    public function setStart(DateTime $start) {
        $this->start = $start;
    }
    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd() {
        return $this->end;
    }
    /**
     * @param DateTime $end
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setEnd(DateTime $end) {
        if ($end < $this->start) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('End before Start');
        }
        $this->end = $end;
    }
    public function hasTime(DateTime $time) {
        return $this->start <= $time and $this->end >= $time;
    }
    public function hasContact(Range $range) {
        return $this->hasTime($range->start)
            or $this->hasTime($range->end);
    }
    public function isSame(Range $range) {
        return $this->start == $range->start
            and $this->end == $range->end;
    }
    public function isWithin(Range $range) {
        return $range->start > $this->start
            and $range->end < $this->end;
    }
    public function isSubset(Range $range) {
        return $range->hasTime($this->start)
            and $range->hasTime($this->end);
    }
    public function add(Range $range) {
        if (!$this->hasContact($range)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Range needs to overlap.');
        }
        if ($range->start < $this->start) {
            $this->start = $range->start;
        }
        if ($range->end > $this->end) {
            $this->end = $range->end;
        }
    }
    public function substract(Range $range) {
        if ($this->isWithIn($range)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Range would divide.');
        }
        if ($this->isSubset($range)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Range would delete.');
        }
        if (!$this->hasContact($range)) {
            return;
        }
        if ($range->start == $this->start) {
            $this->start = $range->end;
            return;
        }
        if ($range->end == $this->end) {
            $this->end = $range->start;
            return;
        }
        if ($range->start < $this->end) {
            $this->end = $range->start;
        } elseif ($range->end > $this->start) {
            $this->start = $range->end;
        }
    }
    public function getDifferenceArray(Range $range) {
        if ($this->isSubset($range)) {
            return [];
        }
        if (!$this->hasContact($range)) {
            return [clone $this];
        }
        if ($this->isWithin($range)) {
            $result[1] = clone $result[0] = clone $this;
            $result[0]->end   = $range->start;
            $result[1]->start = $range->end;
            return $result;
        }
        $result = clone $this;
        $result->substract($range);
        return [$result];
    }
    public function format($format) {
        return [
            $this->start->format($format),
            $this->end->format($format)
        ];
    }
}
class Ranges implements IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    protected $ranges = [];
    public function __construct($ranges = NULL, DateTime $end = NULL) {
        if ($ranges) {
            if ($ranges instanceof DateTime) {
                if (null === $end) {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Need start and end.');
                }
                $ranges = new Range($ranges, $end);
            }
            if ($ranges instanceof Range) {
                $ranges = [$ranges];
            }
            foreach ($ranges as $range) {
                $this->append($range);
            }
        }
    }
    public function getStart() {
        if (!$this->ranges) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Enpty Range');
        }
        return $this->ranges[0]->getStart();
    }
    public function getEnd() {
        if (!$this->ranges) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Enpty Range');
        }
        return $this->ranges[count($this->ranges) - 1]->getEnd();
    }
    public function append(Range $range) {
        if ($this->ranges) {
            if ($range->getStart() <= $this->getEnd()) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Can not append Range that is inside ranged time already');
            }
        }
        $this->ranges[] = $range;
    }
    /**
     * @param Range $range
     * @return Ranges
     */
    public function substractRange(Range $range) {
        $result = new self();
        foreach ($this as $member) {
            /* @var Range $member */
            foreach ($member->getDifferenceArray($range) as $new) {
                $result->append($new);
            }
        }
        $this->ranges = $result->ranges;
    }
    public function substract(Ranges $ranges) {
        $result = clone $this;
        foreach ($ranges as $range) {
            $result->substractRange($range);
        }
        $this->ranges = $result->ranges;
    }
    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->ranges);
    }
    public function getRange() {
        return new Range($this->getStart(), $this->getEnd());
    }
    public function count() {
        return count($this->ranges);
    }
}
```