# PHP - Best Way to Construct Timeline Data From Sets of Beginning and Ending Timestamps

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I have a series of array items that looks like:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:27:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:30:45"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:15:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:22:45"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:10:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:17:45"
}]
```

I would like to build an array off of this array that will allow me to display a timeline of my items.  The timeline will always have one line on the Y axis.  If there are multiple items that overlap each other in the original array, those multiple items would be combined into one item.

For the above array, the result array I am looking for would look like:

```
[{
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:10:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:22:45"
}, {
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:27:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:30:45"
}]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you try sorting them based on the start date and then loop through the array and check if the start of the next index is before the end of the current index, if so merge them, if not it is a new item.

Comment: for working with dateRanges there is a library  - the 2nd anwer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129336/split-a-time-range-into-pieces-by-other-time-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is scarily complex. If its a small number of items then maniuplating the data in PHP or Javascript will suffice, but if its a large number of items, then doing it in a database would be the way to go.

Regarding the smal number of items - you just need to

- sort by start
- iterate through the array and, for each item

  - iterate through later entries in the array to see if they intersect - and if they do merge them

This has order O(n^2) which does not scale well.

Doing this in a database with a conventional index isn't going to help much - these are great for queries filtered by (e.g.)

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.value BETWEEN $a_literal AND $another_literal
```

But such indices do not work for

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE $a_literal BETWEEN t.start and t.end
```

unless the ranges defined in each record are much smaller than total span of the data held in the table.

At that point the solution is to use geospatial indexing and map your time intervals to areas in a 2-D space (because MySQL does not support 1 dimensional geospatial indexing).

Hence a full solution for the problem can be implemented with order O(nlog(n)) but I've wittered on enough about that here.

DBMS are good at handling bulk operations quickly - so the brute force method described originally would run faster in the database than in PHP / Javascript - but the computing resource is easier to scale in PHP and in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using simple `foreach` loop, for achieving desired output. additionally we are checking for `timestamp` and comparing them

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/795689)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$json='[{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:27:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:30:45"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:15:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:22:45"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "start": "2017-04-05 16:10:08",
    "end": "2017-04-05 16:17:45"
}]';
$array=  json_decode($json,true);
$result=array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($result[$value["id"]]))
    {
        //checking which start-time is less
        if(strtotime($result[$value["id"]]["start"]) > strtotime($value["start"]))
        {
            $result[$value["id"]]["start"]=$value["start"];
        }
        //checking which end-time is greater
        if(strtotime($result[$value["id"]]["end"]) < strtotime($value["end"]))
        {
            $result[$value["id"]]["start"]=$value["end"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $id=$value["id"];
        unset($value["id"]);
        $result[$id]=$value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2017-04-05 16:27:08
            [end] => 2017-04-05 16:30:45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2017-04-05 16:10:08
            [end] => 2017-04-05 16:22:45
        )

)
```