# Date range slicing

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I have a list of date ranges and I need to split it based on overlapping dates using php or mysql.

**Sample given below**

**Date ranges**

```
01-11-2018 : 30-11-2018
05-11-2018 : 10-11-2018
08-11-2018 : 15-11-2018
```

I need output as shown below:

```
01-11-2018 : 04-11-2018
05-11-2018 : 07-11-2018
08-11-2018 : 15-11-2018
16-11-2018 : 30-11-2018
```

Comment: Would you show us your attempts and tell us what's wrong with them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129336/split-a-time-range-into-pieces-by-other-time-ranges ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: "overlapping" means you want the date before or after or both ?

Comment: both date ranges