# Calculate opening times with a part of closed time

Tags: php, arrays, time

This is what is given to me:

`$openinghours = ['09:00-18:00'];`

Now there can be multiple pieces of "closed time", for example:

`$closed[] = '11:30-12:15';
$closed[] = '16:00-16:30';`

I need to get the new opening times, like so:

`$openinghours = ['09:00-11:30,'12:15-16:00','16-30-18:00'];`

So it now has the gaps of the closed time in it.

Where do I start? I'm quite at loss on how to calculate this and get the expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129336/split-a-time-range-into-pieces-by-other-time-ranges

Comment: Your arrays does not make sence. Is there supposed to be something like "monday" in them? Are they associative. How do I know $openinghours[0] is linked with both $closed[0] and [1]? What is the logic? Always two "closed" per open?

Comment: It's just a simplified example for a given day, is it really that important if it is monday or not? And there can be multiple 'closed' per day, not just two. They are random, hence the need of a calculation.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a318ad1747152163e2c509027a6fa62613c4ca1

Comment: @splash58 thank you, this looks promising and is basically the same problem!

Comment: @splash58 If you create an answer with this link pointing to the post I will accept yours as the accepted one :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129863/6245144

Answer (score 1):

By exploding all time ranges on hyphens, you can manually piece together the open/close times.

My solution may or may not be robust enough for your project data.  My solution performs no validation, doesn't sort the closed spans, and doesn't check if a span matches an open/close time OR exceeds the open/close time.  My snippet is relying heavily on trustworthy data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A6q13))

```
$openinghours = ['09:00-18:00']; 
$closed[] = '11:30-12:15';
$closed[] = '16:00-16:30';

[$start, $end] = explode('-', $openinghours[0]);
foreach ($closed as $span) {
    [$shut, $reopen] = explode('-', $span);
    $result[] = $start . '-' . $shut;
    $start = $reopen;
}
$result[] = $start . '-' . $end;
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '09:00-11:30',
  1 => '12:15-16:00',
  2 => '16:30-18:00',
)
```

If your php version doesn't support array destructuring, you can call `list()` with `explode()`.

Comment: Great answer! I honestly did not even see this solution when I was trying to process how to get about it. +1

Comment: @Sergeant perhaps consider marking this as the correct answer for future viewers can see.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the quickest way to achieve this, but you can see it [working here](https://3v4l.org/qPogf).

```
$openingHours = ['09:00-18:00'];
$closedHours  = ['11:30-12:15', '16:00-16:30'];

$openStart  = explode("-", $openingHours[0])[0]; # 09:00
$openFinish = explode("-", $openingHours[0])[1]; # 18:00

$hours = [];

foreach($closedHours as $closed)
    $hours[] = explode('-', $closed);

$dynamicHours = ["{$openStart}-"];

for($i = 0; $i <= count($hours) -1; $i++) {
    $dynamicHours[$i] .= $hours[$i][0];
    $dynamicHours[]    = "{$hours[$i][1]}-";
}

$dynamicHours[count($dynamicHours) -1] .= $openFinish;

var_dump($dynamicHours);
```

This gives you an output of

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "09:00-11:30"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "12:15-16:00"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "16:30-18:00"
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, this is not efficient for several reasons.

Comment: Tbh, I didn't actually see your answer because I was trying to attempt this problem for ages lol My answer was legit just the way I could think of doing it, I didn't think to see about exploding all the times and just piecing them together in a new array. @mickmackusa